# Split and restructure an array in ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby, sorting

I have an array, like this: `['host1', '3', '1', '12', 'host2', '4', '1', '5', '1', 'host3', '35', '1'...]` and so on.

Question is - how I can to restructure this array in next:

`['host1', ['3','1','12'], 'host2', [...]]`

or like hash

`{'host1' => ['3','1','12'], 'host2' => [...]}`

Thanks

Comment: First question: **What have you tried?** What defines the separation here?

Comment: Why the rush to select an answer? Others (not me) may very well be still working on their answers.

Comment: nice to meet you, veteran! they are looking for an instant answer, the implementation, quality etc. is not important for them. 
you know, @CarySwoveland, they just want sex, working hard for love is not their deal -))

Comment: The array equivalent to your hash is `[['host1', ['3','1','12']], ['host2', [...]]]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming your keys will start with a non-digit (EDIT: but you should definitely clarify, as @tadman asks):

```
array = ['host1', '3', '1', '12', 'host2', '4', '1', '5', '1', 'host3', '35', '1']

result_array = array
  .slice_before { |e| !e.match(/^\d/) }
  .flat_map { |e| [e.shift, e] }
# => ["host1", ["3", "1", "12"], "host2", ["4", "1", "5", "1"], "host3", ["35", "1"]] 

result_hash = Hash[*result_array]
# => {"host1"=>["3", "1", "12"], "host2"=>["4", "1", "5", "1"], "host3"=>["35", "1"]}
```

EDIT: As @Stefan says, this is shorter:

```
result_array = array.slice_before(/^\D/).flat_map { |e| [e.shift, e] }
# => ["host1", ["3", "1", "12"], "host2", ["4", "1", "5", "1"], "host3", ["35", "1"]]
```

Comment: No need for a block, just `slice_before(/^\D/)`

Answer (score 3):

Here's one possible approach for building your first desired output:

```
result = a.
  chunk { |a| !!/^host/.match(a) }.
  map { |bool, group| bool ? group.first : group }
#=> ["host1", ["3", "1", "12"], "host2", ["4", "1", "5", "1"], "host3", ["35", "1"]]
```

From there you can use `Hash[*result]` to get the hash if you need.

Answer (score 2):

```
arr = ['host1', '3', '1', '12', 'host2', '4', '1', '5', '1', 'host3', '35', '1']

arr.each_with_object([]) { |s,a| s[0] =~ /\D/ ? a << [s, []] : a.last.last << s }.to_h
  #=> {"host1"=>["3", "1", "12"], "host2"=>["4", "1", "5", "1"], "host3"=>["35", "1"]}
```

If an element of `arr` does not begin with a digit (i.e., matches `/\D/`) we append the array being built, `a`, with `[s, []]`; else we append `s` to the empty array just created: `a.last.last << s`.

When the first element of arr is passed to the block, and the block variable `s` is set equal to `"host1"`, then since `"host1"[0] =~ /\D/ #=> 0` (`0` being truthy), the initially-empty array `a` becomes `[["host1", []]`.

Next, `"3"` is passed to the block (`s #=> "3"`) and since `"3"[0] =~ /\D/ #=> nil`, we execute

```
a.last.last << "3"
  #=> ["host1", []].last << "3"
  #=> [] << "3"
```

after which

```
a #=> [["host1", ["3"]]
```

The remaining calculations are similar.